# Open URLs in different browsers

Tags: autohotkey

```
global AssocArray := {}
Array := []
Loop, Read, links.txt
    Array.Push(StrSplit(A_LoopReadLine, ";"))
for index, element in Array {
    Browser := Func("Launch").Bind("chrome.exe --options ", "firefox.exe -options ")
    Menu, MyMenu, Add, % element.2, % Browser
    AssocArray[element.2] := element.3
}
Menu, MyMenu, Show

Launch(BrowserPC1, BrowserPC2, ItemName, ItemPos) {
    Browser := A_ComputerName = PC1 ? %BrowserPC1% : %BrowserPC2%
    Run, % Browser AssocArray[ItemName]
    return
}

Format of links.txt:
;Arrays;https://autohotkey.com/docs/Arrays
```

How can I use a different browser in `Launch` depending on whether I am using `PC1` or `PC2`, and which browsers I specify for different menus (which is why I have not simply specified them in `Launch`)? I am getting an illegal character error because of (I assume) the dashes.

Comment: Could you provide a sample `links.txt` that we can use to debug the program?

Comment: I have added the format of links.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is here:

```
Browser := A_ComputerName = PC1 ? %BrowserPC1% : %BrowserPC2%
```

You're trying to use dynamic variables.
When in an expression statement, you don't refer to variables via the legacy AHK way of wrapping them in `%`s. You just simply type their name, like so:

```
Browser := A_ComputerName = PC1 ? BrowserPC1 : BrowserPC2
```

Another thing. Where is the variable `PC1` supposed to be defined?
Did you maybe mean to use it as a literal string (`"PC1"`)?

Comment: Thank you; the script is working, except that `BrowserPC2` is launched when I am on `PC1` (which is defined separately).

Comment: The ternary says to use the contents of the variable `BrowserPC1`  if the condition `A_ComputerName = PC1` returns true. So there's nothing wrong with it there. Is your issue maybe with scopes? (the variable `PC1` would be defined outside of the function's scope) If so, add `global PC1` to be the first line inside your function.